# MoveIt Setup Assistant ROS Jade

Tags: ros, moveit, catkin, moveit-setup-assistant, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the preferred method for installing the MoveIt Setup Assistant with ROS Jade? Do I need to build from source?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217049/moveit-setup-assistant-ros-jade/) by [user12821821](https://answers.ros.org/users/2936/user12821821/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2015-09-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Do I need to build from source?

Looking at [ros.org/debbuild/jade?q=moveit](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/jade?q=moveit) (and [wiki/moveit_setup_assistant](http://wiki.ros.org/moveit_setup_assistant)), it looks like it hasn't been released for Jade yet.

Building from source would seem to be your only option.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4